# javascript Function runs into infinite loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The following code runs into an infinite loop. Why? How do I prevent that?

The problem seems to be the `$('.skill-levels').append(formattedskillvalue);` line.

```
var HTMLskillstart = '<ul class="skills"></ul>';
var HTMLskill = '<li class="skill-item">%data%</li>';
var HTMLskillLevel = '<div class="skill-levels"></div>';
var HTMLlevel = '<div class="level" width="%data%"></div>';

var skills = {
    'Html': '70%',
    'css': '60%',
    'javascript': '50%',
    'C': '70%',
    'C++': '60%'
};


skills.display = function() {
    var i = 0;
    $.each(skills, function(key, value) {
        $('.skillset').append(HTMLskillstart);
        var formattedskill = HTMLskill.replace("%data%", key);
        var formattedskillvalue = HTMLlevel.replace("%data%", value);
        $('.skills:last').append(formattedskill, HTMLskillLevel);
        $('.skill-levels').append(formattedskillvalue);
        i++;
        console.log(i);
    });
}

skills.display();
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a look at my edit just now, and keep those changes in mind for the future: Put the problem statement up front. Format code readably. Use correct punctuation, spacing, etc.

Comment: What does your HTML look like?

Comment: Maybe put the skill into a sub level. when you call `skill.dispaly()`, it loops over `display` again. Something is wrong.

Comment: hmmm ... `HTMLskillLevel` is added on each iteration, which creates a div class='skill-levels' ... then you append formattedskillslevel to all of them ... not sure why it would become infinite, but it surely is wrong just by the look of it

Comment: This code makes no sense at all. Apart from the mistake explained by *@T.J.Crowder*, The HTML created inside `$.each()` loop is totaly messed up. `<div>` element is not allowed to be a child of `<ul>`. `width` attribute is not applied to `<div>` elements. Writing: `$('.skill-levels').append(...)` you're doubling the number of `.level` elements on each iteration (as each iteration a new `.skill-levels` element is created). And on a side note - avoid DOM modifications inside loops... I believe, you're trying to make [**something like this**](https://jsfiddle.net/ho0ovos9/)?

Answer (score 3):

It's a fairly subtle problem: `display` is a property of `skills`, so of course `$.each` will eventually call your callback with `key = "display", value = (the function)`. Then when you do:

```
var formattedskillvalue = HTMLlevel.replace("%data%", value);
```

`replace` sees a function, and so it calls it. (`replace` supports you using a function for the replacement rather than a string.) So you end up recursing forever.

Either don't make `display` a property of `skills`, or make it non-enumerable, or put a guard in the `$.each` callback that skips the code for `key == "display"`.

Here's an example with a non-enumerable `display`:

```js
var HTMLskillstart = '<ul class="skills"></ul>';
var HTMLskill = '<li class="skill-item">%data%</li>';
var HTMLskillLevel = '<div class="skill-levels"></div>';
var HTMLlevel = '<div class="level" width="%data%"></div>';

var skills = {
  'Html': '70%',
  'css': '60%',
  'javascript': '50%',
  'C': '70%',
  'C++': '60%'
};


Object.defineProperty(skills, "display", {
  value: function() {
    $.each(skills, function(key, value) {
      $('.skillset').append(HTMLskillstart);
      var formattedskill = HTMLskill.replace("%data%", key);
      var formattedskillvalue = HTMLlevel.replace("%data%", value);
      $('.skills:last').append(formattedskill, HTMLskillLevel);
      $('.skill-levels').append(formattedskillvalue);
    });
  }
});

skills.display();
```

```html
<div class="skillset"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Well spotted! Of course, `console.log(key,value)` inside the function would expose this kind of issue, no doubt.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol: As does stepping through the code with a debugger. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Hey all I found the answer .
   $.each(skills, function(key, value) this code iterates through the objects key value pairs.

skills.display() is also a part of the object hence at the end of the loop it gets called and gets appended . This in turn makes the loop run again causing the program to enter infinite loop